# How do you preserve precision when scaling a Decimal?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can you scale a [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal), but keep its original precision? E.g.,

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> Decimal('0.1230')
Decimal('0.1230') # Precision is 4.
```

Multiplication does not preserve the original precision:

```
>>> Decimal('0.1230') * 100
Decimal('12.3000') #  Precision is 6.
>>> Decimal('0.1230') * Decimal('100')
Decimal('12.3000') # Precision is 6.
```

The [`.shift()`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.shift) method only keeps the same number of decimal places when shifting by a negative amount:

```
>>> Decimal('0.1230').shift(2)
Decimal('12.3000') # Precision is 6.
>>> Decimal('0.1230').shift(-2)
Decimal('0.0012') # Precision is 2.
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [`.scaleb()`](https://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal.scaleb) method will scale a decimal number while preserving its precision. From the documentation:

> scaleb(other[, context])
>
> > Return the first operand with *exponent* adjusted by the second.

The key part is that the *exponent* gets adjusted and thus maintains precision.

```
>>> Decimal('0.1230').scaleb(2)
Decimal('12.30') # Precision is 4.
>>> Decimal('0.1230').scaleb(-2)
Decimal('0.001230') # Precision is 4.
```

Comment: Unfortunately having tried this it is untrue.  e.g.:

>>> Decimal('174.593701100493291278326069004833698272705078125')
Decimal('174.593701100493291278326069004833698272705078125')
>>> 
>>> Decimal('174.593701100493291278326069004833698272705078125').scaleb(-2)
Decimal('1.745937011004932912783260690')

Comment: @BerndWechner The problem you're running into is the default decimal context precision is 28 (accessible from `decimal.getcontext().prec`). Once you perform any operation on a decimal exceeding that precision the result will be rounded. E.g., `Decimal('174.593701100493291278326069004833698272705078125') + Decimal('0') == Decimal('174.5937011004932912783260690')`.

Comment: Indeed. And hence a @dawg's solution with a localcontext is essential for creating a localcontext with the required precision.

Answer (score 1):

Use [setcontext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.setcontext):

```
>>> mycontext=decimal.Context(prec=4)
>>> decimal.setcontext(mycontext)
>>> decimal.Decimal('0.1230')*decimal.Decimal('100')
Decimal('12.30')
```

If you want something that feels more local, use [localcontext](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.localcontext) and a context:

```
import decimal as dec

with dec.localcontext() as ctx:
    ctx.prec=4
    d1=dec.Decimal('0.1230')*100

d2=dec.Decimal('0.1230')*100

>>> d1, d2
12.30 12.3000
```

If you want something where the lesser precision representation (with no decimal integers use a default) you can do something like:

```
def muld(s1, s2, dprec=40):
    with dec.localcontext() as ctx:
        d1=dec.Decimal(s1)
        d2=dec.Decimal(s2)
        p1=dprec if '.' not in s1 else len(d1.as_tuple().digits)
        p2=dprec if '.' not in s2 else len(d2.as_tuple().digits)
        ctx.prec=min(p1, p2)
        return d1*d2

>>> muld('0.1230', '100')
12.30
>>> muld('0.1230', '1.0')   
0.12
```

Comment: I like this, but it would be nicer still if it shared a method for determining the existing precision of a given Decimal value.

Answer (score 0):

From the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/33948596/47078, you could do something like the following. I'm not sure, though, if what you want is possible without additional code: namely to have a Decimal that preserves precision automatically.

```
>>> import decimal
>>> f = decimal.Context(prec=4).create_decimal('0.1230')
>>> f
Decimal('0.1230')
>>> decimal.Context(prec=4).create_decimal(f * 100)
Decimal('12.30')
```

You may want to write your own class or helper methods to make it look nicer.

```
>>> Decimal4 = decimal.Context(prec=4).create_decimal
>>> Decimal4('0.1230')
Decimal('0.1230')
>>> Decimal4(Decimal4('0.1230') * 100)
Decimal('12.30')
```

Looks like (from [decimal.Context.create_decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal.Context.create_decimal)) you can also do it this way:

```
# This is copied verbatim from the Python documentation
>>> getcontext().prec = 3
>>> Decimal('3.4445') + Decimal('1.0023')
Decimal('4.45')
>>> Decimal('3.4445') + Decimal(0) + Decimal('1.0023')
```

Perhaps you could create a method to replace Decimal() that creates the Decimal object, and updates the global precision if the current precision is less than the current.

```
>>> def make_decimal(value):
...     number = decimal.Decimal(value)
...     prec = len(number.as_tuple().digits)
...     if prec < decimal.getcontext().prec:
...         decimal.getcontext().prec = prec
...     return number
...
>>> make_decimal('0.1230')
Decimal('0.1230')
>>> make_decimal('0.1230') * 100
Decimal('12.30')
```

You would then want a `reset_decimal_precision` method or an optional parameter to `make_decimal` to do the same so you could start new calculations. The downside is that it limits you to only one global precision at a time. I think the best solution might be to subclass Decimal() and make it keep track of precision.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid explicitly specifying the precision, but maybe this is the only solution. I would end up with something like: `number = decimal.Decimal('0.1230'); decimal.Context(prec=number.as_tuple().digits).create_decimal(number * 100)`